# How change the default meeting request format from Rich Text to HTML in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, html, microsoft-outlook-2013, meeting-request

There are options to change the format for **new mails** like this:

[image]

But how can we change the format for new meeting request? The option seen above is not present in the menu tabs. The problem with Rich Text, is with the placement of attachements.

Is there a way to change the default format to HTML?